# Wireless does not work on laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have been having problems with the wireless  network connection on my laptop for a while. (Samsumg Np905S3g) All drivers should be up to date, as well as windos updates. I have tried a clean install of the computer, but I still have the same problem. (Both win7 and win8)

I have problems loading webpages, often the page timeout, other times I fails to load for example images while text is displayed ok. While this happens I have 5 bars on the connection messure icon, and internet is working fine on my other devices. Reseting the router or reconnecting the network connection normally fixes the issue. I have also tried several different channels on the router.

Any ideas what could be wrong or how to start debugging the issue?

Comment: Does it happen with other connected devices (like mobile) or just your laptop?

Comment: just the one laptop

Comment: I should also add that downloading torrents and large files normally works great. If there first is a connection on an item it tends to download very fast, the problem is getting it to start.